# class invalid for deserialization - Deserializes from file working but not blob?

Tags: java, mysql, serialization, blob, deserialization

The problem lies when trying to deserialize an instance of the class itemSet returned in a resultSet after querying my database. The blobfile seems to be fine itself and the data can be saved to a file then correctly read using a filereader (see below) as such I'm inclined to believe the issue lies somewhere in my implementation? The program runs on tomcat using the netbeans 8.01 ide.

My project git link: https://github.com/feltax/gw2apiMark2

My project is using a modified wrapper for a few classes: https://github.com/feltax/gw2apiModified

The exact error:

```
type Exception report message me.nithanim.gw2api.v2.api.items.ItemInfo; 
class invalid for deserialization
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception java.io.InvalidClassException: me.nithanim.gw2api.v2.api.items.ItemInfo; class invalid for deserialization
 java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(ObjectStreamClass.java:150)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(ObjectStreamClass.java:790)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1775)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
Persistance.DbConnect.getItemSets(DbConnect.java:134)
Servlets.TestServlet.doPost(TestServlet.java:84)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

note the full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.27 logs.
```

**Relevent code:** (sorry about the links, this is the first time I've asked for help so I had to butcher them)

DB Connection code: issue occurs on line 134
[github.com/feltax/gw2apiMark2/blob/master/src/main/java/Persistance/DbConnect.java](http://github.com/feltax/gw2apiMark2/blob/master/src/main/java/Persistance/DbConnect.java)

ItemInfo class:
[github.com/feltax/gw2apiModified/blob/master/src/main/java/me/nithanim/gw2api/v2/api/items/ItemInfo.java](http://github.com/feltax/gw2apiModified/blob/master/src/main/java/me/nithanim/gw2api/v2/api/items/ItemInfo.java)

ItemSet Class:
[github.com/feltax/gw2apiMark2/blob/master/src/main/java/ItemSets/itemSet.java](http://github.com/feltax/gw2apiMark2/blob/master/src/main/java/ItemSets/itemSet.java)

my Database:
[imgur.com/zfPLSsq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DToGu.jpg)

**Things I have tried:**

Serial UID Declaration, ensuring all classes implement serializable and have a generated serialUid (also without serialUID).

Remaking the database any time I change a class and thus reseralising all objects stored within.

Ensuring the blob file is correct by saving it to file in mysqlworkbench and then reading in the object with the code below. The itemSet read in fine and the files were identical.
[github.com/feltax/gw2apiMark2/blob/master/src/main/java/Persistance/apiDump.java](http://github.com/feltax/gw2apiMark2/blob/master/src/main/java/Persistance/apiDump.java)

Implementing De-compressible input stream: [github.com/feltax/gw2apiMark2/blob/master/src/main/java/Persistance/DecompressibleInputStream.java](http://github.com/feltax/gw2apiMark2/blob/master/src/main/java/Persistance/DecompressibleInputStream.java)

Trying to serialize and deserialize byte array, input streams and using get object

Finally I asked for help on reddit but I didn't really get far. here: [www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/4i68fj/java_class_invalid_for_de_serialization_error/](http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/4i68fj/java_class_invalid_for_de_serialization_error/)

**New things I have now tried:**

Adding a simple no-args constructor to basicItem and rebuilding the code/database, still getting the same error unfortunately.

```
  public BasicItem() {
  }
```

-- Suggestion thanks to EJP

As a thought, could this be something to do with a single item appearing in multiple itemSets? Does java have a problem deseralising an object that it's already deseralised before?

Comment: Does `BasicItem` have an accessible no-args constructor?

Comment: Thanks for replying, BasicItem did not have a no-args constructor. I have added a simple one (below) rebuild the project and recreated the database. Unfortunately it's still giving the same error.

'public BasicItem()  {  }'

Comment: Hmm, that's what the message usually indicates. I should have asked whether the nearest *non*-serializable parent class has such a constructor. NB Java *loves* deserializing objects it has already deserialized. It handles cyclic object graphs in full generality. I'm wondering why you're serializing this data at all actually, rather than mapping it properly into SQL.

Comment: Hello, I've had a look and added constructors to all the classes in the wrapper that were missing them. Unfortunately this murdered the saved api lists I had and I need to recreate them, this will be a few hours before I find out if this works or not. I'll let you know when I do.
As for why, Mostly time constraints. I'm not the strongest coder. I did try and map them all first but it took weeks and I had barely gotten anywhere. It's more than possible that there are many better ways to do this, however this is what I have and there's no time left to change it. So I'm stuck with it.

Comment: You don't need to modify all the classes: only the ones that are nearest non-serializable base classes of serializable classes.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I added a constructor to all the classes that were any part of the ItemSet Class, so ItemInfo, ScoreValues, Details, Infix and infusion ect, as well as the Base classes of BasicItem and details. Rebuilt the wrapper and the Program, then the lists and it worked. I'm ecstatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: me.nithanim.gw2api.v2.api.items.ItemInfo; class invalid for deserialization
```

The reasons advanced in the Javadoc are as follows:

> Thrown when the Serialization runtime detects one of the following problems with a Class.
>
> - The serial version of the class does not match that of the class descriptor read from the stream

In this case the error message would say so, showing both values.

> - The class contains unknown datatypes

I've never seen this and I'm not convinced it's correct. I would expect that to cause `ClassNotFoundException`.

> - The class does not have an accessible no-arg constructor.

This is not correct. What it should say is that the class's *nearest non-serializable parent* class doesn't have an accessible no-arg constructor. I suspect that is the problem in this case. NB If `BasicItem` is `Serializable` it doesn't need such a constructor.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I've added the missing constructor to the parent classes and it's working now. I'll mark this one as an answer as its clearer than the comment chain we had.

Comment: Curious that it worked with the file. I couldn't see how that can have been true so I decided to ignore it as a false positive.